Add additional handelbar template files to generate history tables and triggers
I'm using EFC.Scaffolding.Handlebars for generating Entities and DBContext (https://github.com/TrackableEntities/EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Handlebars).
Now, I'm looking for a way to generate history tables and triggers for each table in the database into *.sql files. One thought is to add additional *.hbs files that gets process by the EFC.Scaffolding.Handlebars framework.
The goal is to generate the below code for each table in the database with some logic to exclude some tables.
Is that somehow possible?
Thanks
Roland
-- Given
create table Project
(
    Beschreibung        varchar(100),
);

-- To generate
create table Project_History
(
    Beschreibung                     varchar(100),
);

create or alter trigger TG_Project_Audit
    on Project
    after update, delete
    as
begin
    insert
    into Project_History(...)
end;

